# Joining 2 columns to create an account flow query

Tags: php, mysql

i have two tables, one for clients credit(payments) , it looks like this :

```
id     client     date              amount
1       ana       2012-01-01        5000  
2       ana       2012 02-01        10000
3       ana       2012-03-01        5000
```

etc ..

and another table for debit (withdrawals) that looks like this :

```
id    client      date             amount 
1       ana       2012-01-15        5000
2       ana       2012 02-15        8000
3       ana       2012-03-15        9000
```

etc ...

i would like to generate a query that orders all transactions for each client by date ,combining the 2 date columns into one then ordering by date, it should  look like this :

```
date           payment     withdrawal 
2012-01-01     5000           ----
2012-01-15     -----          5000
2012-02-01     10000          ----  
2012-02-15     -----          8000
2012-03-01      5000          ----
2012-03-15     -----          9000
```

this is what i tried but i know its wrong and it gave duplicate records:

```
SELECT payments.amount, payments.date withdrawals.amount, withdrawals.date
FROM payments,withdrawals 
WHERE payments.client = withdrawals.client
ORDER BY date
```

i tried the LEFT JOIN but it gave the same result:

```
 SELECT payments.amount, payments.date, withdrawals.amount, withdrawals.date
 FROM payments 
 LEFT JOIN withdrawals 
 ON payments.client= withdrawals.client
 ORDER BY date
```

Please help and thank you

Comment: Do you use client as foreign key? What if ana misspelled her name, and changed it later to Annabel? Try to use not changeable types like ID's for this kind of relations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do two simple SELECT queries, one on each table separately, then combine the results using the UNION keyword, something like this:

```
SELECT date, amount AS payment, NULL AS withdrawal FROM payments WHERE client = 'ana'
UNION ALL
SELECT date, NULL AS payment, amount AS withdrawal FROM withdrawals WHERE client = 'ana'
ORDER BY date
```

You don't want to do any kind of join, because each row's data is pulled from only one table and not the other.

Answer (score -1):

What you are looking for is a FULL OUTER JOIN:

```
SELECT payments.amount, payments.date, withdrawals.amount, withdrawals.date
FROM payments FULL OUTER JOIN withdrawals
  ON payments.client= withdrawals.client
Order by date
```

Or with a UNION (as needed by MySQL):

```
SELECT payments.amount, payments.date, withdrawals.amount, withdrawals.date
FROM payments LEFT OUTER JOIN withdrawals
  ON payments.client= withdrawals.client
Order by date
UNION
SELECT payments.amount, payments.date, withdrawals.amount, withdrawals.date
FROM payments RIGHT OUTER JOIN withdrawals
  ON payments.client= withdrawals.client
Order by date
```

Comment: It depends on the type of database you are using, for mysql you should use the UNION, since it doesn't do FULL OUTER JOIN

Comment: im doing this through PHP like this : $query= mysql_query("SELECT ... ");
while($person = mysql_fetch_array($query))
 {echo $person['client'];echo $person['date']; echo $person['amount'];
echo "<BR>";}